# Extract the results plotted in the margin of the levelplot function

Tags: r, raster, levelplot

How can i extract the results plotted in the margin of the levelplot function?

Or is there a function that does the same thing?

I'm searching for something like a table...

Best regards,

```
    library(raster)
    library(rasterVis)
    library(gridExtra)
    
    f <- system.file("external/test.grd", package="raster")
    r <- raster(f)
    x <- levelplot(r, margin=T)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the help page of `rasterVis::levelplot`:

> [These] marginal graphics show the column (x) and row (y) summaries of
> the `Raster*` object. The summary is computed with the function
> `mean`.

You should use the `raster::zonal` function to compute them:

```
rx <- init(r, 'x')
mx <- zonal(r, rx, FUN = mean)
plot(mx, type = 'l')
```